# case statement with in clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a section table that has a total of 6 sections. I want to insert a different status based on the section. So Basically if Sectionid = 1,2,5,6 then the status would insert a 1 elseif the section is 3,4 then the status would insert a 0. I need this to insert a status for all 6 sections. I tried using a case statement but that is not working.

Table: `Section`:

```
sectionkey int
sectionint int

sectionkey  sectionint
   1            1
   2            2
   3            3
   4            4
```

Table `Status`:

```
statuskey int
statusint int
sectionint int
```

Desired output:

```
    statuskey  statusint sectionint
      1            0          1
      2            0          2
      3            1          3
      4            1          4
```

I want to be able to insert lets say section 1 and 2 into the status table and make the status 0 but also insert sections 3 and 4 into the status table but make their status equal 1 all in one statement.

```
   DECLARE @SECTION int
   DECLARE @STATUS int
   --SET @SECTIONID = (SELECT SECTIONID FROM Section)

   SELECT CASE @STATUS 
   WHEN (SELECT SECTIONID FROM Section WHERE SECTIONID IN(1,2,5,6)) THEN '0' ELSE WHEN (SELECT SECTIONID FROM Section WHERE SECTIONID IN(3,4)) THEN '1' END END
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO Checklist ("SECTIONID", "STATUS", "USERID")
   SELECT s.SECTIONID,@STATUS, @USER
   FROM SECTION as s 
   END
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.) Additional schema
information and where your attempts failed would also help us to help you better.

Comment: Dan I edited my question to include the information you asked for also my statement failed as a whole if that makes since. And I understand why its failing just dont understand how to fix it.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into Checklist("SECTIONID","STATUS","USERID")
    (select SECTIONID, (case when SECTIONID in(1,2,5,6) Then 0 Else 1 END), @USER
    from Section)
```